# images divs are not responsive with smaller screen size

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

i have a 3 divs containg images in one section. they are aligned in one row on the large screen. but  they are not responsive on smaller screens . I need them to be responsive so they are below each others
Thanks in advance

```
<section id="about">
        <h1>undrawa illustration</h1>
        <div class="about-container">
            <div class="image-container">
                <h2>web innovation</h2>
                <img src="img/undraw_feeling_proud_light.svg" alt="" id="image1">
            </div>
            <div class="image-container">
                <h2>web innovation</h2>
                <img src="img/undraw_conceptual_idea_light.svg" alt="" id="image2">
            </div>
            <div class="image-container">
                <h2>web innovation</h2>
                <img src="img/undraw_proud_coder_light.svg" alt="" id="image3">
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hi, interesting, perhaps a flexgrid might work so the items will flow? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

Comment: can you attach your css too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't include your CSS but I assume you have something like this:

```
.about-container{
        display: block;
    }
    .image-container{
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

You need to write separate rules for mobile displays. Try:

```
<style type="text/css">
/* Mobile CSS */
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .about-container{
        display: block;
    }
    .image-container{
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

And your HTML:

```
<div class="about-container">
<div class="image-container">
    1
</div>
<div class="image-container">
    2
</div>
<div class="image-container">
    3
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: section{
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
}
.image-container{
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: centers;
  position:flex ;
  width:40% ;
  
}
.image-container img{
 display: block;
 height: auto;
 min-width: ;
}
}

Comment: The code above will definitely work. Add the mobile media query below your CSS code.

Comment: Thanks. But  there's other problem with h1 elements in the page. They don't fit

Comment: The heading elements don't fit on mobile?

Comment: If the heading elements overflow the screen on mobile, then  use CSS to set their max-width to 100% or something less, just like we have for image-container, under the mobile query. Set the display of "about" to block as well, just as we have for about-container.